# Display taxonomy page using CPT UI

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom post type called Resource Library and a custom Taxonomy called Resource Categories using the Custom Post Type UI plugin for wordpress. I having trouble querying the categories on the taxonomy page template. I'd be very grateful if someone could help me out with this.

Here is the code I have in my taxonomy-resource-categories.php file:

```
    <?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'resource-library',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'resource-categories',
            'field'    => 'slug',    
            'terms'    => 'data-sheets',
        ),
    ),
); $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="blog-post-wrap">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<div class="post-thumb blog-index">
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );
} 
?>
</div>
<div class="title-meta-wrap">   

<?php if (strlen($post->post_title) > 75) {
echo substr(the_title($before = '', $after = '', FALSE), 0, 75) . '...'; } else {
the_title();
} ?>
</a>
<p><span class="theauthor"><?php the_date(); ?> <span style="color:#EC7906;"> / </span><?php the_author(); ?> </span></p>

</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating $query object but not using that object in your loop. So, replace your loop with this code.

```
<?php while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();  ?>
```

Then your query will have data and you can use your data according to your needs. Hope that helps